# Random Lottery with unequal weights

Tags: javascript

I have a list of 100 people. Each person has purchased a varying number of tickets. The data is passed to me in json. So it would be like "John Smith 100 tickets, Jane Doe 55 tickets, etc." I need to randomly select 100 winning tickets giving each ticket the same probability of being selected. I have figured out how to use the fisher Yates shuffle I just can't ungroup the data to give each ticket holder the same chance. I need to create 55 Jane tickets and 100 john tickets, etc and shuffle them and select only the first 100.
Thank you for any direction.

Comment: Please post some sample code of what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: I have the fisher Yates part to shuffle the data.http://jsfiddle.net/Gamedevtuts/pvVhy/1/

Comment: I just don't have the example of how to take John Doe with 100 tickets and make 100 john doe cards and 55 Jane doe cards and shuffle them.

Comment: There has to be an easy way to do this I just can't think of the right verbiage to use my googlefu on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of shuffling the list of people, create an array with one element for each person *for each ticket that person has,* and shuffle and draw from that array.

So instead of:

```
['John Smith', 'Jane Doe', ...]
```

You'd have:

```
['John Smith', 'John Smith', 'John Smith', ..., 'Jane Doe', 'Jane Doe', ...]
```

There are, of course, more memory-efficient ways, but this is a start.

Comment: Do you have any sample code of how to do this? Make 100 items in an array based on the Qty value in JSON. This is where I was hoping to get to. Thanks for responding.

Comment: That's a pretty elementary task with JavaScript. I'm not going to spoon feed the answer to you; give it a shot yourself. Use a `for` loop.

Comment: No problem. I can Google away from here. I am new to coding and got hung up on this problem. Thanks.